# Dynamic relationships

Tags: sql-server, table-relationships

For example look at tables below:

tblItems:

```
ItemName   IDData    Type
-------------------------
 i1         1         1
 i2         2         1
 i3         1         2
```

tblData1:

```
IDData     Name
-------------------
 1          Data11
 2          Data12
```

tblData2:

```
IDData     Name
-----------------
 1          Data21
 2          Data22
```

In `tblItems` columns of type 1 have a `IDData` from `tblData1` and if type was 2 `IDData` associated to tblIDData2.

records should be inserted in data tables and then user can insert a record to item table so I have to set a relationship to ensure that.

in this case how to set Relationships between these tables in `Sql Server`?

Comment: @SaUce That's right, I think this is my answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

I believe something like this will fit your needs:

```
SELECT 
 item.ItemName
 ,CASE item.Type
   WHEN 1 THEN data1.Name
   WHEN 2 THEN data2.Name
   ...add more?
  END
FROM tblItems item
JOIN tblData1 data1 ON data1.IDData=item.IDData AND item.Type=1
JOIN tblData2 data2 ON data2.IDData=item.IDData AND item.Type=2
```

Comment: I know how to make queries for getting result of these three tables.

Comment: So, what's the problem then? #lost

Comment: I updated the question check it again ;)

Answer (score 0):

I would modify your structures to fit to the following

tblItems:

```
ItemName   IDData    Type
-------------------------
 i1         1         1
 i2         2         1
 i3         1         2
```

tblData

```
IDData     Name           Type
--------------------------------
 1          Data11         1
 2          Data12         1
 1          Data11         2
 2          Data12         2
```

Now in your table `tblItems` `IDData` and `Type` would be foreign keys. In new `tblData` you need to create composite primary key to include `IDData` and `Type` now when joining tables you do not need to have weird logic.

Comment: in this example your answer is OK, but in reality I have different table structure for each one of the data tables so I can't mix them in one table.

Comment: You can not have foreign key to multiple tables. It has to be only between two tables.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't define a relatioship in this case.. (in SQLSERVER)...

the relationship will need to be in your code. (c#, java, others)..

You can use a sql to simulate it using conditionals like `case, when`

But not like you want.

Other way to do that is create another structure to your tables...

like this:

```
IDData     ItemName   ItemType (this itemtype would be 1 or 2 representing the Data)
```

Hope it helps.